# how do i get a specific data from array using tad php master API

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, zkteco

I have an array like the code bellow:

```
Array ( [Row] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [PIN] => 269 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:00:10 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [PIN] => 56 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:00:33 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [PIN] => 99 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:00:46 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [PIN] => 99 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:00:49 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [PIN] => 213 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:01:02 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [5] => Array ( [PIN] => 193 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:01:06 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [6] => Array ( [PIN] => 271 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:04:43 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [PIN] => 271 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:04:52 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [8] => Array ( [PIN] => 54 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:04:56 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [9] => Array ( [PIN] => 247 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:07:22 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [10] => Array ( [PIN] => 225 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:17:07 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [11] => Array ( [PIN] => 375 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 00:48:06 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [12] => Array ( [PIN] => 273 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:03:47 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [13] => Array ( [PIN] => 273 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:03:50 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [14] => Array ( [PIN] => 282 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:15:52 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [15] => Array ( [PIN] => 362 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:26:02 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [16] => Array ( [PIN] => 196 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:26:06 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [17] => Array ( [PIN] => 52 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:26:46 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [18] => Array ( [PIN] => 32 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:26:59 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 0 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [19] => Array ( [PIN] => 362 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:27:10 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [20] => Array ( [PIN] => 32 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:27:20 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [21] => Array ( [PIN] => 52 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 01:27:24 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [22] => Array ( [PIN] => 176 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 03:00:40 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [23] => Array ( [PIN] => 176 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 03:00:44 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [24] => Array ( [PIN] => 182 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 03:01:02 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [25] => Array ( [PIN] => 226 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 03:01:41 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [26] => Array ( [PIN] => 226 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 03:01:45 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 1 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [27] => Array ( [PIN] => 175 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 06:39:54 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 0 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [28] => Array ( [PIN] => 313 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 06:41:36 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 0 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [29] => Array ( [PIN] => 206 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 06:43:44 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 0 [WorkCode] => 0 ) [30] => Array ( [PIN] => 305 [DateTime] => 2019-04-03 06:55:23 [Verified] => 0 [Status] => 0 [WorkCode] => 0 ) ) )
```

I want to get only the PIN numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just loop the array like this way :

```
foreach($data['Row'] as $item){ // $data is the array that contain all data
  echo $item['PIN'];
}
```

if you want to store those pin numbers into an array :

```
 $pins = array();
foreach($data['Row'] as $item){
  $pins[]=$item['PIN'];
}
var_dump($pins); // that will show an array of pins [269,99,...]
```

If you want  to convert the *$pins* array to **json** :

```
$pins_json= json_encode($pins,true);
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: what's the name of variable contain the whole data ? don't copy-paste code, you have to modify the name of variable $data . may be you are namming it somehow different to $data

Comment: $tad_factory = new TADPHP\TADFactory();
        $comands = TAD::commands_available();
        $info =array();
        $IP = '203.177.160.230';
        $b1 = (new TADFactory(['ip'=>'127.0.0.1']))->get_instance(); 
        
         $att_logs = $b1->get_att_log();

         $filtered_att_logs = $att_logs->filter_by_date(
            ['start' => '2019-04-03','end' => '2019-04-03']
        );

        $logs = $filtered_att_logs->to_array();
        foreach($logs['row'] as $item){ // $data is the array that contain all data
            echo $item['PIN'];
          }

Comment: delete 'row' from $logs i mean ,  foreach($logs as $item){

Comment: Undefined index: PIN

Comment: sorry , make Row instead of row

Comment: Its ok now. but i need to convert it to json format and fetch the data.

Comment: i don't really understand that point ? can you explain , you said that you want to extract only the pins , and what do you want to convert to json , the array of pins or something else ?

Comment: the first problem is solve but . the out put is  this 26956999921319327127154247225375273273282362196523236232521761761822262261753132063052012341891898238811037437 . which is the pins but I need to insert each pins not this compressed numbers of pins.

Comment: try the second snnipet not the first, in the second one i'm storing pins into an array . check the second code snippet

Comment: Thank you sir its ok now :D

Comment: use json_encode if you want to convert the array of pins to json format .

Comment: enjoy the great PHP